# Best way to redefine nginx parameters for search bots

Tags: nginx

On our site we automatically serve different content based on user's geolocation. To achieve this we pass variable with host's IP address to our fcgi application.

Problem is, we want to serve *all* of the content for search bots, so I would like to pass non-existent IP specially for these cases.

So far I've come up with this chunk of configuration code (as soon as nginx don't know about "else"):

```
location / {

  if ( $http_user_agent ~* Googlebot ) {
    set $remote_addr_googled "0.0.0.0";
  }

  if ( $http_user_agent !~* Googlebot ) {
    set $remote_addr_googled $remote_addr;
  }

  fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr_googled;

}
```

Аre there any other, more effective, ways around?

Comment: danlefree provided really useful link about cloaking and geolocation as Google sees it. Guess we'll consider changing the way we treat search bots now. 

Anyway, I'm still interested in finding more effective ways to redefine nginx parameters based on some condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The key is to treat Googlebot as you
>   would a typical user from a similar
>   location, IP range, etc. (i.e. don't
>   treat Googlebot as if it came from its
>   own separate country—that's cloaking).

[Official Google Webmaster Blog: How Google defines IP delivery, geolocation, and cloaking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-google-defines-ip-delivery.html)

**Update:** You can use the [nginx embedded perl module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxEmbeddedPerlModule) for if/then/else conditionals.

Comment: @smugglerFlynn - I'd be hesitant incorporate any spider-specific rules (if only for the fact that it's more work with questionable benefit if the same information is immediately available on a more specific URI)

Comment: yeah, thanks, you are right on this. We decided to make a separate page, with listing of all geolocation-dependant items available on site at once. Still, it would be great to know more ways (if any) to specifically redefine variables in nginx, not just for this particular case